# Error occurs while copying from previously generated org to a new org

Tags: apex, dmlexception

I have used the below code previously in an org(two years before) - version 28

```
public class GSScBPSyncStep1{
  public String run{get;set;}
  BpSyncConfiguration__c  configValue;

  //constructor  for step1 
  public GSScBPSyncStep1(){
    configValue = [Select Step1__c,step1_final__c from BpSyncConfiguration__c limit 1];
    system.debug('(configValue.Step1__c:::+++:'+configValue.Step1__c);  
    if(configValue.step1_final__c == null ){
      run= 'Initial';
    }else {     
      run= 'Full';
    }
  }
  //Method for list values
  public List<SelectOption> getItems() {
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>(); 
    system.debug('(configValue.Step1__c::::'+configValue.Step1__c);
    if(configValue.step1_final__c == null ){        
      options.add(new SelectOption('Initial','Initial Load(On-Demand;one time)')); 
      options.add(new SelectOption('Full','Full-Sync (On-Demand;Ocassinoal)')); 
    } else {
        options.add(new SelectOption('Full','Full-Sync (On-Demand;Ocassinoal)'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Delta','Delta Load'));
    } 
    return options; 
  }
  //method for next button
  public PageReference CustomSave(){
    system.debug('configValue.run::::'+run);
    configValue.Step1__c  = run; 
    configValue.Step2__c  = 'SAP';    
    system.debug('configValue::::'+configValue);
    update configValue;
    if(run == 'Full') {
        return new PageReference('/apex/GSSvBPSyncStep3');
    } else if(run == 'Delta') {
        PageReference pageRef = Page.GSSvMasterDataSync1;
        //PageReference pageRef = Page.GSSvMasterDataSync;
        pageRef.getParameters().put('LoadType','Delta');
        return pageRef;
    } else {
        return new PageReference('/apex/GSSvBPSyncStep3');
    }
  }
  //method for back button
  public PageReference back(){ 
    return new PageReference('/apex/GSSvBPSyncIntro');
  }
}
```

Now I want to use the same code in different org but it throws error as

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Do version in apex class affect it?

Please suggest a solution for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like some data is not present in the new org. I bet that you need a record in BpSyncConfiguration_c.